TV Movie about giant muppets holding a little person prisoner
Anyone know the name of this  movie, or what story it was derived from?
This movie appeared on PBS somewhere between 1988 to 1993. The story was about a knight (played by some real life little person) being held by giants (portrayed by giant 7' tall muppet-type things similar to what Jim Henson has done in the past). It may have been shown on Masterpiece Theater.
The little knight kept trying to escape but the giants were too big and strong. I don't know why but I got the impression that the story was from classical literature somewhere. I believe there was a little person female as well being held by the giants, possibly the knight's wife or a damsel in distress. It was a medieval or fantasy setting obviously. I believe he was imprisoned in the standard small cylindrical hanging cage. 
It was not a comedy, rather a serious sad story about the knight's imprisonment and torment. He just wanted to go home and found them cruel and their ways foreign.  I don't remember any other details of the plot, as it was 20 years ago or so. The visual style was very unusual and twisted due to the choice of characters and the way they contrast and very macabre.

It feels like one of the "Jack and the beanstalk" stories. But I haven't found one that matches your time-frame.

I'd guess Jim Henson's Storyteller, possibly the True Bride episode with the trolls, but no little people, it wasn't PBS, and it's earlier than the timeframe (at least on UK first-airing, and too late on HBO first-airing).

My guess was also Storyteller (but it sounds more like the Heartless Giant episode to me) or Time Bandits, but I don't think anything there contains these exact details.

I read through the description of the episodes in Storyteller. It doesn't seem to be what I saw. I will have to watch the Storyteller though, it looks like something i would like.

Thinking more about it, I remembered the story reminded me of something Edgar Allan Poe would come up with. I did a little research and found it was was a derivative work of Edgar Allan Poe's "Hop-Frog" using puppets from Jim Henson's creature shop. It was called "Fool's Fire"
